# Create a simple line graph in powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to create VBA code that just draws a simple line chart on the first powerpoint sheet.

I wrote the following:

```
Sub createSampeChart()
    Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    myChart = myDocument.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

    With myChart
        .ChartStyle = 4
        .ApplyLayout 4
        .ClearToMatchStyle
        .HasLegend = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Running it however gives me a 438 error however. Any thoughts on what I should adjust?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> myChart = myDocument.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
> ```

Use `Set` when assigning objects:

```
 Set myChart = myDocument.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
'^^^^
```

The rest of your code seems correct and should work fine after this correction, provided you have at least one slide in the presentation.